# Grouping indexes in a Pandas crosstable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe in Pandas that looks like this:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'Age': [21,22,21,23,23,21,21],
    'Region': ['North America', 'Europe East', 'Europe West', 'South America',
               'North America', 'North America', 'Europe West'],
    'Answer': ['yes','yes','no','yes','no','no','yes']})

   Age         Region Answer
0   21  North America    yes
1   22    Europe East    yes
2   21    Europe West     no
3   23  South America    yes
4   23  North America     no
5   21  North America     no
6   21    Europe West    yes
```

And I need a way to produce a cross or pivot table like this:

```py
Answer         no  yes
Continent                
Europe          1    2    
America         2    2
```

Using the Pandas crosstab function I managed to produce this table:

```py
ct = pandas.crosstab(index=df['Region'], columns=df['Answer'])

Answer         no  yes
Region                
Europe East     0    1
Europe West     1    1
North America   2    1
South America   0    1
```

But then I don't know how to group the indexes that have some part of the string in common.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: FWIW, North and South America are conventionally separate continents in the English-speaking world, and it seems like the data reflects that since for Europe it puts "East"/"West" *after* "Europe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the continent name from the region.

```
ct.groupby(
    ct.index.str.extract(r'(Europe|America)', expand=False).rename('Continent'),
    sort=False,
    ).sum()
```

```
Answer     no  yes
Continent         
Europe      1    2
America     2    2
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this solution answers precisely what I asked for, I like very much the other two solutions posted below by you and by @NaumRaskind, because they are more flexible and can be easily adapted to more general cases

Comment: I cant't cast a vote because I am newby to StackOverflow and I still don't have 15 reputation :-(

Comment: @Fernando Oh, huh, I thought you could always vote on answers to your own question. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to get the continent name from a region, and use the resulting series as the index for the data. It would look something like this:

```
def get_continent(region):
    if 'America' in region:
        return 'America'
    if 'Europe' in region:
        return 'Europe'

    return 'Unknown Continent'

continent = df['Region'].apply(get_continent)
ct = pd.crosstab(index=continent, columns=df['Answer'], rownames=['Continent'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) before the crosstab. I imagine this will be more flexible in case you have regions like "China", in which case you can map it to "Asia" instead of having to create a special string matching rule.

```
region_to_continent = {
    'Europe East': 'Europe',
    'Europe West': 'Europe',
    'North America': 'America',
    'South America': 'America',
}
pd.crosstab(
    index=df['Region'].map(region_to_continent).rename('Continent'),
    columns=df['Answer'],
)
```

```
Answer     no  yes
Continent         
America     2    2
Europe      1    2
```

Answer (score -1):

I try to use the goupby and pivot table but it doesn't works  due to duplicates.
However you can try this code : first you  will extract the common part of Region column and then you will build your crosstable

```
import pandas 
df['Continent'] = df['Region'].str.extract('(\w+)', expand=False)
result = pandas.crosstab(index=df['Continent'], columns=df['Answer'])
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but his solution does not work as expected because it produces a table with two indexes 'North' and 'South' instead of one index 'America'